# php class, passing variable into function, referencing the variable

Tags: php, class, reference

I have a class which pulls in Twitter feeds and amalgamates them, they are put into an array ,sorted and combined. I then need to convert the 'published' time from unix to human .

Within my class construct I have:

```
function __construct($inputs) {     

             $this->inputs = $inputs;
             $this->mergeposts();
             $this->sortbypublished($this->allPosts,'published');
             $this->unixToHuman('problem here');
             $this->output();
     }
```

SortbyPublished is

```
        function sortbypublished(&$array, $key) {
$sorter=array();
$ret=array();
reset($array);
foreach ($array as $ii => $va) {
    $sorter[$ii]=$va[$key];
}
arsort($sorter);
foreach ($sorter as $ii => $va) {
    $ret[$ii]=$array[$ii];
}

    $this->sorted = $ret;
```

}

unixToHuman is :

```
public function unixToHuman($unixtime) {
            $posts['published'] =   date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $unixtime);
            }
```

My problem is I cannot work out what I need to enter into :

```
$this->unixToHuman('HERE');
```

Part of this I believe is due to my lack of understanding of PHP terminology, which is making it hard to find anything in the manual . Am I trying to reference the 'published' array?

What I need is the correct version of :

```
$this->sorted['published']
```

I hope this makes sense , any help at all , especially with the terminology greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like unixToHuman wants a timestamp. So you could use [date()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php), or the timestamp of whatever time you want to convert to human readable time.

```
$this->unixToHuman(date());
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, the `unixToHuman` method needs to return a value, so let's do this:

```
public function unixToHuman($post) {
    $post['published'] =   date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $post['published']);
    return $post;
}
```

Then we can pass in our rows one at a time in your `__construct` method:

```
foreach ($this->sorted AS $idx => $row) {
    $this->sorted[$idx] = $this->unixToHuman($row);
}
```